# Normal closure of $A$ vs $\langle A\rangle$

Tags: group-theory

Let $A\subseteq N\triangleleft G$. Denote $A^c$ the normal closure of $A$ (intersection of all normal subgroups of $G$ containing $A$) and $\langle A\rangle$ the subgroup generated by $A$ (intersection of all subgroups of $G$ containing $A$). We can prove that $\langle A\rangle=N$ implies $A^c=N$. Can we prove that $A^c=N$ implies $\langle A\rangle=N$? What if $G$ is free?

Comment: Hint: Try with A being a non-normal subgroup that is maximal in N.

Comment: $N$ is a normal subgroup of what?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft thanks, I'll try to find this construction!

Comment: @DerekHolt actually the main group can be any group but I'm also interested in the case of free groups.

Comment: You need to make clear whether you mean the normal closure of $A$ in $N$ or the normal closure of $A$ in $G$ - they could be different. But the answer to your question is no in any case.

Comment: @DerekHolt thanks, you're right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**General case.** No. Let $A$ be a subgroup of $G$ that is not normal. Then $\langle A\rangle=A\neq A^c$.

**Free groups.** No. Let $G$ be a free group generated by a set $S$ such that $|S|\geq 2$. It is sufficient to show that not all subgroups of $G$ are normal. Indeed, if $x$, $y$ are distinct elements of $S$, then $xy\in x\langle y\rangle$ and $xy\notin \langle y\rangle x$.

**Abelian groups.** Yes. Obviously, $\langle A\rangle\subseteq A^c$. But we also have $A^c\subseteq\langle A\rangle$ since $\langle A\rangle$ is normal and $A\subseteq\langle A\rangle$.